# What is VMD spray paint A002L3

Tags: paint, varnishing, spray-paint

I bough this product which is a transparent varnish with gloss, with this code **LUCIDO**:-

[image]

But when i open the can i found that it has this code **A002L3**, as follow:-

[image]
[image]

so not sure why i got 2 codes? and what is the use for **A002L3**?. i already applied it to a blue varnish table,, before i realize that the outside code is different than the inner code. where it gave a MATT transparent finish ..
So have any one used VMD-A002L3 before?

any advice?

**EDIT**

Here is how another can looks like for the same product "transparent gloss varnish:-

[image]

where the inner code is the same as the outer code.

Answer (score 3):

The "outer" number/text **is** the paint code.

The "inner" number/text is a batch, date, or other quality control code. This is used on all kinds of consumer products. These types of codes are how things like [the JIF Peanut Butter recall](https://jms-s3-mkt-consumer-p-pmc6.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/recall.html) are done. If a month (sometimes it is just a few days) of production of a product is contaminated in some way, this allows for a recall notice to target only the problem product and not "everything".

Comment: thanks for the update, can you check my edit, where i checked another can and it has the inner and the outer code the same, unlike the first can..